# Choosing interaction language for an action

Tags: actions-on-google

The Actions documentation says that an action may interact in a language of its choice other than the language setting of the user. There is a checkbox on the Invocation page allowing you to use a voice other than the one matching the users language setting.

However, the choice of voices is limited to those in that language. I need to speak and, more importantly, to listen in a specific language and not that set by the user (this is for language teaching).

This doesn't seem to be a mainstream use case but I wonder if there is some workaround through the API or by uploading an action that enables settings not accessible through the DialogFlow GUI.
Speaking in another language is achievable with some inconvenience using recordings, but the inability to listen is a showstopper.

Similar questions have been asked before but new languages and features appear all the time - maybe the current Actions API supports more than is widely known?
I believe Alexa has the same limitation, as well as a shorter list of supported languages.

Answer (score 0):

The selection of TTS voices is constrained by the language selected by the user. Speech recognition is also biased towards the language configured by the user.

Comment: This is what I observe yes Leon. My question concerns whether there are any subtle workarounds for the application to make an arbitrary selection of especially recognition language.

Comment: There isn't a way for developers to do that.

Comment: Coming from a Google Developer Programs engineer I take that as a definitive answer! I hope though that you will take this to your colleagues as a legitimate use case, as it would be great to use Assistant as a language teaching tool. Thank you for being clear.